# DemComponents configurations

Tags: embedded, autosar, automotive

I'm new to AUTOSAR. I currently have a EB Tresos installed and licensed and I'm trying to navigate through all the DEM configurations with the specification of DEM written by AUTOSAR. This document: https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/standards/R20-11/CP/AUTOSAR_SWS_DiagnosticEventManager.pdf#page=86&zoom=100,285,988

So, one of my questions is - I look at Tressos and I can't find the DemComponent configurations. I understand it is a container under the **DemConfigSet** container, but I don't see anywhere. why is that? is it not mandatory? I don't have to configure it?

I opened DEM configuration under ECU, and looked for a DemConfigSet configuration and in there I don't see any DemComponent configurations. [Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m1Qm.png)